# axios TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

First, I use cdn script tag in html for using axios now.

In `api.js`, I create axios instance like this :

```js
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "/api",
});

export default {
  test: () => api.get("/test/results"),
};
```

and I use it in another js file (`test.js`) like this :

```js
import API from "/api.js";

const getSearchData = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios(API.test());
    console.log(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

then I got following error and also `console.log(res);` didn't working.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at isAxiosError.js:10
    at isAxiosError.js:10
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.exports (isAxiosError.js:10)
    at e.exports (isAxiosError.js:10)
    at async getSearchData (test.js:17)
```

but In network pannel (chrome browser), it works very well. It's status code was 200.

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/test/results
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I can't understand it. How can I fix it? I have no idea what's wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to call `axios` second time here `await axios(API.test());`. Your `api` is already an `axios` instance which you made with `axios.create` call earlier.

So just change code to this:

```
import API from "/api.js";

const getSearchData = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await API.test();
    console.log(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```